# Datadog: Add Enrichment Table to Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, datadog

Is it possible to add an Enrichment Table to a Dashboard? I could not find anything in the documentation and Enrichment Tables are not listed under the Widgets that can be added to a Dashboard.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge in DataDog goes you will need to add a lookup processor and enrich some existing log
once you will do that you can build log-based widgets within the dashboard

take a look [here](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/add-context-with-enrichment-tables/)

Comment: I think you mean "lookup processor", not "lockup processor" (though it would be nice to have a processor for lockups :)